# How to get around JSON Decode error while retrieving token from arcgis rest server?

Tags: python, arcgis-server, json

I'm trying to create a script that lets a user check for non-nullable fields in all feature classes in all feature services published to a server. However, I'm running into an issue with just the first step--getting a token from the target server. When I run the code, I get a JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) which, to me, implies the JSON is wrong. However, I can't figure out -why- its wrong or what to do next. Here's the current code.

```
def getToken(username, password, serverName, serverPort):
    #Token URL is typically http://server[:port]/arcgis/admin/generateToken
    tokenURL = "/arcgis/admin/generateToken"
    
    params = urllib.parse.urlencode({'username': username, 'password': password, 'client': 'requestip', 'f': 'json'})
    
    headers = {"Conent-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Accept": "text/plain"}
    
    # Connect to URL and post parameters
    httpConn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(serverName, serverPort)
    httpConn.request("POST", tokenURL, params, headers)
    
    # Read Response
    response = httpConn.getresponse()
    if (response.status != 200):
        httpConn.close()
        print("Error while fetching tokens.")
        return
    else:
        data = response.read()
        httpConn.close()
        
        # Check data returned is not an error object
        if not assertJsonSuccess(data):
            return
        
        # Extract the token
        token = json.loads(data)
        return token['token']

# a function that checks the input json object is not an error object.
def assertJsonSuccess(data):
    print(json.dumps(data.decode("utf-8")))
    obj = json.loads(data)
    if 'status' in obj and obj['status'] == "error":
        print("Error: JSON object returns an error." + str(obj))
        return False
    else:
        return True

# set definition for reading location
    # Ask for admin username and password
username = input("Enter user name: ")
password = getpass.getpass("Enter password: ")
    
    # Ask for server name
serverName = input("Enter server name: ")
serverPort = 6443
    
    #Get a token
token = getToken(username, password, serverName, serverPort)
    # If token not found, print error
if token == "":
    print("Could not generate a token with the username and password provided.")
print(token)
```

I added the print(json.dumps(data.decode("utf-8")) to try and figure out what was wrong with the JSON, but the first line of that decoded is: "<html lang="en">\n  \n    Generate Token\n which doesn't look incorrect to me.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around for this that finally worked to get a token. I believe part of the problem is how outdated and wonky ESRI's sample codes were, which is what I was working off of. The code that ended up working is below.

Basically, I just used a completely different library, the requests library, and was able to get the token without issue.

```
# Create request variables to get into the server
username = input("Enter user name: ")
password = getpass.getpass("Enter password: ")
# Ask for server name
serverName = input("Enter server name): ")
# Server port will usually be 6443. Default is also 6080 for some arcGIS stuff. Hardcoded since all
# our current servers use 6443
serverPort = "6443"

# create token URL
tokenURL = "https://" + serverName + ":" + serverPort + "/arcgis/admin/generateToken"
# Print the url for testing
#print(tokenURL)
# Set params
params = {'f':'pjson', 'username': username, 'password': password, 'client': 'requestip'}

#request the token using the requests library
token = requests.post(url=tokenURL, data=params)
```